# Simple 'require' problem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, require

I'm following along with 'Why's Poignant Guide to Ruby' in order to learn Ruby and I am having some problem when he first introduces the 'require' method(?) in his tutorial.

Essentially I make a file called 'wordlist.rb' which contains:

```
  code_words = {
  'starmonkeys' => 'Phil and Pete, those prickly chancellors of the New Reich',
  'catapult' => 'chucky go-go', 'firebomb' => 'Heat-Assisted Living',
  'Nigeria' => "Ny and Jerry's Dry Cleaning (with Donuts)",
  'Put the kabosh on' => 'Put the cable box on'
}
```

I then have another ruby scipt called 'files.rb':

```
require 'wordlist'

#Get evil idea and swap in code words
print "Enter your new idea: "
idea = gets

#real will have the key and code will have the value
#Method followed by ! (like gsub!) are known as destructive methods
code_words.each do |real, code|
    safe_idea = idea.gsub!( real,code )
end

#Save the jibberish to a new file
print "File encoded. Please enter a name for this idea: "
idea_name  = gets.strip

File::open( "idea-" + idea_name + ".txt", "w") do |f|
    f
```

When I try to run the Ruby script i get:

```
files.rb:9: undefined local variable or method `code_words' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Any idea how to get the 'require' to work properly to reference wordlist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem with local variable. You can look [here](http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2005/09/12/getting-rubys-require-to-work-in-the-poignant-guide-to-ruby/) - there is exactly the same problem with a solution.