# 'Require' method won't work - help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting to learn Ruby, and I've been following Why's (poignant) guide. At one point, I create a file titled 'wordlist.rb', within which is the following code:

```
code_words = {
  'starmonkeys' => 'Phil and Pete, those prickly chancellors of the New Reich', 
  'catapult' => 'chucky go-go', 'firebomb' => 'Heat-Assisted Living', 
  'Nigeria' => "Ny and Jerry's Dry Cleaning (with Donuts)",
  'Put the kabosh on' => 'Put the cable box on'
}
```

Another script calls the 'require' method on the wordlist file....

```
require 'wordlist'

 # Get evil idea and swap in code words
   print "Enter your new idea: " 
   idea = gets
   code_words.each do |real, code| 
     idea.gsub!( real, code )
   end

 # Save the jibberish to a new file
   print "File encoded.  Please enter a name for this idea: " 
   idea_name = gets.strip
   File::open( "idea-" + idea_name + ".txt", "w" ) do |f|
     f << idea
   end
```

Now, for whatever reason, I get this error when I try to run the script above:

test.rb:5: undefined local variable or method `code_words' for main:Object (NameError)

It's definitely finding and loading the wordlist.rb file (the method is returning true), but I can't seem to access the code_words Hash. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943406/simple-require-problem-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

code_words is a local variable inside wordlist.rb.

What you can do:

- define a gloibal variable ( $wordlist)
- define a constant (WORDLIST)
- define another container, e.g. a class which provides the data

Comment: Thanks Knut, I'll try the above. Do I define code_words as a global/constant within wordlist.rb, or within the file that requires it?

Comment: You have to do it within wordlist.rb. Your application can use it later.

Comment: @knut are you sure you mean $wordlist and not $code_words as the global variable? wordlist is the file name, code_words is the hash name.

Comment: The name itself is not important. But if I define a constant for usage outside a file, the I prefer a similarity between filename and constant. So I would rename `code_words` to `WORDLIST`. But if you prefer you could keep the name and use `$code_words`.